# How to make a task without converting iterable to dictionary?

Tags: python

The function creates a generator for this object. The stream generator must be equal to the original stream.

```
gen = gen_stream (9, [(4,111), (7,12)])

list (gen) [0, 0, 0, 0, 111, 0, 0, 12, 0]
```

Code:

```
from itertools import count

def gen_stream(total, sorted_iterable, extractor=lambda x: x):
    sorted_iterable = dict(map(extractor, sorted_iterable))
    iterable = count() if total is None else range(total)
    for i in iterable:
        yield sorted_iterable.get(i, 0)

#gen = gen_stream(9,[(4,111),(7,12)])
#list(gen)
```

output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 111, 0, 0, 12, 0]
```

Now the question is: How to make a task without converting iterable to dictionary?
as I understand it here:

```
sorted_iterable = dict(map(extractor, sorted_iterable))
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do everything with looping over index and reading one element at a time from the input iterable when needed, so that if the input is produced by some generator you do not unnecessarily store all of it in memory.

The variable `next_input` contains the next `(position, value)` pair that we are going to use.

```
def gen_stream(total, sorted_iterable, extractor=lambda x: x):

    if not hasattr(sorted_iterable, '__next__'):
        sorted_iterable = iter(sorted_iterable)

    input_finished = False
    next_input = ()
    for i in range(total):
        if (not input_finished and
            (next_input == () or i > next_input[0])):
            try:
                next_input = next(sorted_iterable)
            except StopIteration:
                input_finished = True
        if input_finished or next_input[0] > i:
            yield 0
        else:
            yield extractor(next_input[1])
    
gen = gen_stream(9, [(4,111), (7,12)])
print(list(gen))
```

Answer (score 0):

I write this for you. When I finish I found alaniwi already answered your question. -_- So this is just persernal opinions, only for reference.

```
from itertools import count


def gen_stream(total, sorted_iterable, extractor=lambda x: x):
    sorted_iterator = iter(sorted_iterable)  # transform to iterator
    iterable = count() if total is None else range(total)
    try:  # get first value
        current_extracted_record = extractor(next(sorted_iterator))
    except StopIteration:
        current_extracted_record = None
    for i in iterable:
        if current_extracted_record:
            if i == current_extracted_record[0]:
                try:  # get next value
                    yield current_extracted_record[1]
                    current_extracted_record = extractor(next(sorted_iterator))
                except StopIteration:
                    current_extracted_record = None
            else:
                yield 0
        else:
            yield 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gen = gen_stream(9, [(4, 111), (7, 12)])

    print(list(gen))
```

Comment: Try is used because iterator stopped by StopIteration exception. I don’t know other way to judge the end of an iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Code without converting to dict.

```
from itertools import count 

def gen_stream(total, sorted_iterable, extractor=lambda x: x):
    iterable = count() if total is None else range(total)
    for i in iterable:
        for j in sorted_iterable:
            j = extractor(j)
            if i == j[0]:
                yield j[1]
                break
        else:
            yield 0
```